# Joining item in list of strings with a string outside of list

Tags: python

Most of the solutions I've come across involve joining items within a list, but my question is about joining an item from a list of strings with another string outside of the list.

In the script below, the desired output is `"USD.JPY.SPOT.SPR"` as a string, and then the subsequent pairings.

I've tried `pairing.join(".SPOT.SPR")` and `pairing+".SPOT.SPR"` but they've not generated the desired output.

```
pairings = ["USD.JPY", "USD.HKD", "AUD.USD", "EUR.USD", "GBP.USD", "USD.SGD"]
for pairing in pairings:
    print(pairing.join(".SPOT.SPR"))
```

Comment: What *is* the desired output and why did `pairing+".SPOT.SPR"` did not give it? You've only shown `"USD.JPY.SPOT.SPR"` which is a single string. What is your desired output from the list?

Answer (score 0):

Try iterating through the list index and '+' to concatenate -

```
pairings = ["USD.JPY", "USD.HKD", "AUD.USD", "EUR.USD", "GBP.USD", "USD.SGD"]
for i in range(len(pairings)):
    print(pairings[i]+(".SPOT.SPR"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your join with string concatenation

```
pairings = ["USD.JPY", "USD.HKD", "AUD.USD", "EUR.USD", "GBP.USD", "USD.SGD"]
for pairing in pairings:
    print(pairing+".SPOT.SPR")
```